# Basic question about Markov Chain stationary distribution using generating functions

Tags: markov-chains, generating-functions

This is really basic, but I've been trying hard for a while and didn't get where I made a mistake, so after some consideration decided to ask it here.

So I got a basic recurrence equation for stationary distribution in MC:
$$
0=\lambda \pi_{k-1} + \mu \pi_{k+1} - (\lambda+ \mu) \pi_k
$$

I tried to solve it using generating functions with $G(z)=\sum_{k \geq 0} \pi_k z^k$, so I got

$$
\frac{\mu \pi_0}{z}=P(z)(z-1)(\lambda-\frac{\mu}{z})
$$
I understand how to go from here equating coefficients and so on, but this expression is incorrect! The correct one is

$$
\frac{\mu \pi_0(1-z)}{z}=P(z)(z-1)(\lambda-\frac{\mu}{z})
$$
before cancellations. I suspect I made a mistake when working out the generating function $G(z)$:
$$
\lambda \sum_{k \geq 0} \pi_{k-1} z^k=\lambda z G(z)\\
\mu \sum_{k \geq 0} \pi_{k+1}z^k = \frac{\mu}{z}(G(z)- \pi_0)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, start with:
$$
0 = \lambda \pi_k + \mu \pi_{k + 2} - (\lambda + \mu) \pi_{k + 1}
$$
Define:
$$
P(z) = \sum_{k \ge 0} \pi_k z^k
$$
Applying properties of ordinary generating functions:
$$
\begin{align*}
0 &= \lambda P(z) 
        + \mu \frac{P(z) - \pi_0 - \pi_1 z}{z^2} 
        - (\lambda + \mu) \frac{P(z) - \pi_0}{z} \\
P(z) &= \frac{(\mu \pi_1 - (\mu + \lambda) \pi_0) z + \mu \pi_0}
             {(1 - z) (\lambda z - \mu)}
\end{align*}
$$
(This is a second order recurrence, need starting values $\pi_0$ and $\pi_1$.)

[Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net)'s help with algebra is gratefully aknowledged.

Comment: I don't understand, why this does not work with the original recurrence? Is it because of $\pi_{-1}$ term?

Comment: @Alex, you'd need $\sum_{k \ge 0} \pi_{k - 1} z^k = z P(z) + \pi_{-1}$ for a $\pi_{k - 1}$.

Comment: Which does not exist, right? So this was my mistake then. Thanks.

Comment: @Alex, If you want, you certainly can compute a $\pi_{-1}$ to match the recurrence (compute backwards, as it where).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand, could you explain in greater detail how this can work?

Comment: @Alex, use the recurrence on $\pi_{-1}$, $\pi_0$ and $\pi_1$ to get $\pi_{-1}$ from $\pi_0$ and $\pi_1$.

Comment: Do you mean that the first term would be $\pi_{-1}$ rather than $\pi_{0}$?